# Replacing mysql_real_escape_string():

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

As mysql_real_escape_string is now deprecated, I have to change one function on the site that is using it. For the life of me, I can't figure out proper mysqli or pdo code to use. Maybe someone can guide me at the right direction. This is how it currently looks.

```
    if (isset($_GET['btnSearch']) && !empty($_GET['txtSearch'])) {

        $txtSearch = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['txtSearch']));

        if (preg_match("/^(?i)BAW[0-9]+/", $txtSearch)) {
            $pilot->pilot_num = strtoupper($txtSearch);
        } else {
            $pilot->name = $txtSearch;
        }
    }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: you don't escape data in PDO and MySqli. you use prepared statements.

Comment: the best for you is to start reading about PDO (my favorite) because your problem is not only this code  as you say

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it appears, I already have open connection and framework handles the query. All that needed is removal of

mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 2):

To replace mysql_real_escape_string with mysqli_real_escape_string you need to have an already opened connection to your DB like this:

```
$DBH = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpasswd, $database_name);
```

then you can replace

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['txtSearch'])
```

with

```
$DBH->real_escape_string($_GET['txtSearch'])
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you suggest to open connection to database? In the same file? This is the only place I use real_escape.

Comment: I always use the same connection for this. By the way, if the code above is placed in some function you may pass needed value as already escaped.